# Create a PDF file with PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I want to create pdf file from my web page written by php . My document must produce from mysql and produce pdf file.I want to be to save this pdf and to read.Please give me code sample.

Comment: You can use for example [TCPDF](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf) library to generate PDFs. This site also has some code examples. As for fetching and manipulating the data from your db you will have to code this yourself.

Comment: I think [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org) Provides most simple way to create PDFs with sample codes given on site as well. Here you can find with example [http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script10.php](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script10.php)

Comment: @bb. could you take a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925076/php-creating-a-pdf-how-can-i-get-this-working-errors-populating/16925161?noredirect=1#16925161

Answer (score 13):

Using the [TCPDF](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf) library:

```
<?
require_once("tcpdf/tcpdf.php");
$pdf = new TCPDF();

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor("my name");
$pdf->SetTitle("my doc");
$pdf->SetSubject("x");
$pdf->SetKeywords("a, b, c");


// set default header data
$pic = "/gfx/header.png";
$pdf->SetHeaderData(realpath($pic), "25", "Title");

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

//set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

    //set auto page breaks
 $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

 //set image scale factor
 $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

 //set some language-dependent strings
 $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

 //initialize document
 $pdf->AliasNbPages();

 // add a page
 $pdf->AddPage();

 // ---------------------------------------------------------

 // set font
 $pdf->SetFont("helvetica", "", 12);

 // set a background color
 $pdf->SetFillColor(230, 240, 255, true);


$pdf->SetFont("", "b", 16);
$pdf->Write(16, "some text\n", "", 0, 'C');

$pdf->Output("filename.pdf", "I");
?>
```

Comment: I test this code.But I found error at
 $pdf->Write(16, "some text"\n", "", 0, 'C');

$pdf->Output("filename.pdf", "I");

these lines.How do I solve?

Comment: there was a " too much. sorry. it's fixed now

Answer (score 1):

I you already have an HTML page, the fastest way for you might be to use a tool like [HTML2PDF](http://html2pdf.spipu.net/index_en) to "convert" that HTML data to PDF, instead of generating a PDF file "from scratch".

Quoting that page :

> It allows the conversion of valid HTML
>   4.01 in PDF format, and is distributed under LGPL.
>
> This library has been designed to
>   handle mainly TABLE intertwined to
>   generate invoices delivery, and other
>   official documents. It does not yet
>   have all the tags.

There are some example of HTML, and the corresponding PDF files, so you can see what's capable of.

Comment: How Can I add page number to html2pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Download newest version of TCPDF source code from https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-pdf , The Source code itself have a directory which the folder named as examples. you can check out the code from the examples or else you can try below code.

```
<?php

require_once('tcpdf/config/tcpdf_config.php');
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set default font subsetting mode
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
// set margins
//$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
//$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', 'Hello ','Gudmrng', array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
$pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

 // set default monospaced font
 $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

 // set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// Set font
// dejavusans is a UTF-8 Unicode font, if you only need to
// print standard ASCII chars, you can use core fonts like
// helvetica or times to reduce file size.
 $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10, '', true);
 //     $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
  // Add a page
 // This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->AddPage();
 $tbl_header = '<h2 style="color:blue;text-align: center;font-size: 14px;">Headding</h2></br>';

 $html = '<table width="530" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="1">
                    <tr>
                    <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 10px;font-weight: bold;width:100px;">heading 1</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;font-size: 10px;font-weight: bold;width:122px;">heading 2</th>
                    </tr>';
                        $html .= '<tr>';
                        $html .=  '<td><b>Hello World</b></td>';
                        $html .= '<td><b>Helo </b></td>';
                        $html .=  '</tr>';
                        $html .=  '</table>';


 $pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header . $html, true, false, false, false, '');
 //$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0);
 //$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0);


  $pdf->Output('test_1.pdf','I');

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i used CutyCapt  for do that.

1. download  and install [a CutyCapt](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjmwpfvmbfQAhWJFSwKHd72CGEQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcutycapt.sourceforge.net%2F&usg=AFQjCNGE1hDsp03VVuVAbK5j6s_4MTat1g&sig2=B48lnm8-u4eTDFQ1y1-Z0w&bvm=bv.139250283,d.bGg) !  and xvfb-run .
2. make pdf style in html page and then create pdf from this page by this command:

xvfb-run cutycapt --min-width=1485  --url='html url'   --out='path to pdf'