# how to convert website posts to pdf?

Tags: php, pdf, web

I have a PHP site in which I have Button Named save as PDF for each post of site.

When I Click this Button I need to save the subject of the post and post contents as PDF and Display it.

I dont use any asp.net code in my site.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You want to generate the pdfs for yourself only, or for all of your users?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a PDF file with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204630/create-a-pdf-file-with-php) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365698/create-pdf-pages-in-php

Comment: @ Marc B : I want to generate pdfs for all of users.

Answer (score 2):

I like [PrintFriendly.com](http://www.printfriendly.com/button) but this might not be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check  [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) ?