# How to make pdf of html page of invoice?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a PDF file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204630/create-a-pdf-file-with-php)

I have created invoice generator using javascript. well I am able to work on it. Now what I have to do is I have to generate the data in the pdf which are available in the invoice. I tried some but none work out. So If there is anyone who can help me out?

Thanx in advance

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2006/jw-0410-html.html Hope this link will guide you, after that implementation should be a cakewalk.

Comment: @Sundar Ban: You are invited to use the search feature of this website before asking a question. As you can imagine, you might not be the first person on earth who would like to know how to create a PDF with PHP.

Answer (score 2):

I have used ["webkit html to pdf" (wkhtmltopdf)](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) several times.

It worked well for me, although working with page breaks is a bit of an hassle.

Answer (score 2):

PDF cannot be generated at the client side (I mean with Javascript). You will need to process the invoice data at the server side using a PDF library and write to a URL location, so that it can be downloaded or opened in a browser.

TCPDF is a good tool to generate PDF with PHP. See this [link](http://www.tcpdf.org/).

Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204630/create-a-pdf-file-with-php).