# PHP auto generate pdf file?

Tags: php, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a PDF file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204630/create-a-pdf-file-with-php)

Me and my friend are creating a user based feedback website, now when someone posts a project of theirs and it's over 5,000 characters for example we want to be able to link a user to a pdf of that project.  Now we don't know how to generate a pdf, we don't want saved pdf files on our server we just want the contents of the posts from the database displayed on a pdf.  Thanks for any help, very much appreciated!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php

Comment: I'd rather http://www.tcpdf.org

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/). It looks like it has some of the functionality you are looking for.