# How to split HTML Page in A4 size in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to create something like in Xing the CV maker -> https://lebenslauf.com/.

I do have different Arrays of Objects.
But I am not able to create the A4 pages which will render the data and if the array it is larger than one page create new page A4 and add data there.
The function needs to be so if the array is larger for one size, then create a new page a4 and put the data there.
In the stackblitz I have added an array and some random text and designed an A4 letter.
I referred to this question and answer, but didn't help me too much.
[CSS to set A4 paper size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649943/css-to-set-a4-paper-size).
I tried to fake pagination and to create A4 sizes but didn't work.
I looked in this code with jquery there. It works, but I am unable to compile it in Angular.
https://jsfiddle.net/tm637ysp/10/
Can someone help me here ?

I have created two projects in stackblitz. Maybe they will help.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fjhpdu.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uzmdwg

I wanted to reopen this question because the approved answer from @HirenParekh it doesn't work as I wanted.
The problem it is now, If the text in one Object it is very large it wont add a new page in a realtime, but only if I reload the page.
I think that the code will be for add new page or edit page will be rendered only in `ngOnInit`.
The directive that is provided to do that job, I think it is not working as excepted.
Here is the  `stackblitz` what he tried to help me.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zjf8rv

This is the code I am trying to show data.

```
    <div style="transition: transform 0.25s ease 0s;transform: scale(1.3);transform-origin: 50% 0px 0px;backface-visibility: hidden;perspective: 1000px;display: block;margin: 0px 11.5385%;font-size:10px;width: 76.9231%;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;">
<app-paginated-view [pageSize]="'A4'" *ngIf="model" class="Grid-grid-column">
  <div pageContent class="row">
    <div class="col col-lg-7">
      <h4>{{currentUser?.firstName}} {{currentUser?.lastName}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-right">
      <input type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="readUrl($event)">
      <img [src]="url" (change)="readUrl($event)" height="128" style="cursor:  pointer">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div pageContent class="Unit-unit-unitGroup"
   *ngFor="let personalData of model.personalData; let id = index">
   <div pageContent [ngClass]="{ 'isCatActive': selectedCategory === category.PersonalData}">

   <ng-container *ngIf="selectedCategory === category.PersonalData" clickOutside (clickOutside)="removeClick()">
    <ul>
      <li class="fa fa-plus addIconTop" (click)="openDialog()"></li>
      <li class="fa fa-plus addIconBottom" (click)="openDialog()"></li>
      <li class="fa fa-trash deleteIconRight" (click)="deleteCategory(index)"></li>
      <li class="fa fa-arrow-down moveIconDown"></li>
      <li class="fa fa-arrow-up moveIconTop"></li>
    </ul>
  </ng-container>

    <div pageContent class="col-md-12" (click)="setCategory(category.PersonalData)">
      <div class="row height">
      <div  class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-right tLine"></div>
      <h3 class="first-template-paragraphTitle Paragraph-paragraph-title height">
        <div class="Text-text-wrapper">
          <div class="Text-Text-text">{{'category.PersonalData' | translate}}</div>
        </div>
      </h3>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div pageContent class="container-fluid">
      <ng-container>
      <app-personal-data [personalData]="personalData" [model]="model" [id]="id">
    </app-personal-data>
  </ng-container>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

    <!-- Career Component -->
    <ng-container *ngFor="let careers of model.careers" class="Unit-unit-unitGroup">
      <div pageContent class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row height">
        <div  class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-right tLine"></div>
        <h3 class="first-template-paragraphTitle Paragraph-paragraph-title height">
          <div class="Text-text-wrapper">
            <div class="Text-Text-text">{{'category.Career' | translate}}</div>
          </div>
        </h3>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid" pageContent>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let careerObj of careers.subCategories; let i = index">
      <app-career [careerObj]="careerObj" [id]="i" [career]="careers" [model]="model"></app-career>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let emptyObj of careers.emptySubContents; let iEmpty = index">
        <app-empty-object [emptyObj]="emptyObj" [iEmpty]="iEmpty" [model]="model" [isFromCareer]="true"></app-empty-object>
      </ng-container>
        </div>
    </ng-container>

    <!--Education Component-->
    <ng-container *ngFor="let education of model.education" class="Unit-unit-unitGroup">
      <div pageContent [ngClass]="{ 'isCatActive': selectedCategory === category.Education}">
        <ng-container *ngIf="selectedCategory === category.Education" clickOutside (clickOutside)="removeClick()">
          <ul>
            <li class="fa fa-plus addIconTop" (click)="openDialog()"></li>
            <li class="fa fa-plus addIconBottom" (click)="openDialog()"></li>
            <li class="fa fa-trash deleteIconRight" (click)="deleteCategory(index)"></li>
            <li class="fa fa-arrow-down moveIconDown"></li>
            <li class="fa fa-arrow-up moveIconTop"></li>
          </ul>
        </ng-container>
      <div pageContent class="col-md-12" (click)="setCategory(category.Education)">
        <div class="row height">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-right tLine"></div>
          <h3 class="first-template-paragraphTitle Paragraph-paragraph-title height">
            <div class="Text-text-wrapper">
              <div class="Text-Text-text">{{'category.Education' | translate}}</div>
            </div>
          </h3>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div pageContent class="container-fluid">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let educationObj of education.subCategories; let i = index" class="col-md-12">
        <app-education [educationObj]="educationObj" [id]="i" [education]="education" [model]="model"></app-education>
      </ng-container>
      </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>


  <!-- Skills Component-->
    <ng-container *ngFor="let skills of model.skills" class="Unit-unit-unitGroup">
    <div pageContent [ngClass]="{ 'isCatActive': selectedCategory === category.Skills}">
    <ng-container clickOutside *ngIf="selectedCategory === category.Skills" (clickOutside)="removeClick()">
      <ul>
        <li class="fa fa-plus addIconTop" (click)="openDialog()"></li>
        <li class="fa fa-plus addIconBottom" (click)="openDialog()"></li>
        <li class="fa fa-trash deleteIconRight" (click)="deleteCategory(index)"></li>
        <li class="fa fa-arrow-down moveIconDown"></li>
        <li class="fa fa-arrow-up moveIconTop"></li>
      </ul>
    </ng-container>
    <div pageContent class="col-md-12" (click)="setCategory(category.Skills)">
      <div class="row height">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-right tLine"></div>
        <h3 class="first-template-paragraphTitle Paragraph-paragraph-title height">
          <div class="Text-text-wrapper">
            <div class="Text-Text-text">{{'category.Skills' | translate}}</div>
          </div>
        </h3>
    </div>
    </div>
          <div pageContent class="container-fluid">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let skillObj of skills.subCategories; let i = index" class="col-md-12">
        <app-skills [skillObj]="skillObj" [id]="i" [skills]="skills" [model]="model"></app-skills>
      </ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>


</app-paginated-view>
</div>
```

This is the CSS

```
  .A4 {
  width: 595px;
  height: 842px;
  padding: 25px 25px;
  position: relative;
}
```

This is the `json`

```
{
    "personalData": [
        {
  
            "firstName": "Max",
            "lastName": "Muster",
            "email": "max.musterman@outlook.com",
            "birthday": "2020-09-25T00:00:00.000Z",
            "telephone": "0123456789",
            "job": "Freelancer",
            "country": "Germany",
            "postalCode": 12345,
            "city": "None",
            "title": 2,
            "gender": 0,
            "street": "Musterman 12",
            "state": "",
            "status": 1,
            "showBirthday": true
        }
    ],
    "skills": [
        {
            "subCategories": [
                {
                    "languages": [
                        {
                            "name": "languages.de",
                            "rate": 5
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "languages.al",
                            "rate": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "languages.en",
                            "rate": 5
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "languages.fr",
                            "rate": 4
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "languages.it",
                            "rate": 4
                        }
                    ],
                    "pcKnowledge": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5f5ca07e4dba443f786ea7ae",
                            "name": "Word"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f5ca07e4dba443f786ea7af",
                            "name": "Adobe Photoshop"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f5fd46bb21df2444c39f317",
                            "name": "Test"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f5fd46bb21df2444c39f318",
                            "name": "Excel"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f5fd46bb21df2444c39f319",
                            "name": "Ja"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f72339552009b4244391972",
                            "name": "Powerpoint"
                        }
                    ],
                    "skillsOffer": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5f4a4e2d718d33092df2c327",
                            "name": "Angular"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f4a4e2d718d33092df2c327",
                            "name": "Java"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f4a4e2d718d33092df2c327",
                            "name": "Typescript"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f4a4e2d718d33092df2c327",
                            "name": "html"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Javascript"
                        }
                    ],
                    "driveLicenses": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5f5ca07e4dba443f786ea7ac",
                            "name": "B"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f5ca07e4dba443f786ea7ad",
                            "name": "C"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f5f204faa5d0205180bd581",
                            "name": "B"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "",
                    "qualifications": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the `Paginated view class for adding new page and splitting pages`

```
<!-- display: none style will any child that does not have #pageContent local variable defined -->
<div class="content-wrapper" #contentWrapper style="display: block">
</div>
<div class="paginated-view" #paginatedView>

</div>

export class PaginatedViewComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() pageSize: "A3" | "A4" = "A4";

  @ViewChild("paginatedView") paginatedView: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

  @ViewChild("contentWrapper") contentWrapper: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

  @ContentChildren(PageContentDirective, { read: ElementRef })
  elements: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.updatePages();

    // when ever childs updated call the updatePagesfunction
    this.elements.changes.subscribe((el) => {
      this.updatePages();
    });
  }


  updatePages(): void {
    // clear paginated view
    this.paginatedView.nativeElement.innerHTML = "";

    // get a new page and add it to the paginated view
    let page = this.getNewPage();
    this.paginatedView.nativeElement.appendChild(page);

    let lastEl: HTMLElement;
    // add content childrens to the page one by one
    this.elements.forEach((elRef) => {
      const el = elRef.nativeElement;

      // if the content child height is larger than the size of the page
      // then do not add it to the page

      if (el.clientHeight > page.clientHeight) {
        return;
      }
      // add the child to the page
      page.appendChild(el);

      // after adding the child if the page scroll hight becomes larger than the page height
      // then get a new page and append the child to the  new page
      if (page.scrollHeight > page.clientHeight) {
        page = this.getNewPage();
        this.paginatedView.nativeElement.appendChild(page);
        page.appendChild(el);
      }
      lastEl = el;
    });
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();

    // bring the element in to view port
   // lastEl.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "nearest" });
  }

  getNewPage(): HTMLDivElement {
    const page = document.createElement("div");
    page.classList.add("page");
    page.classList.add(this.pageSize);
    return page;
  }
}
    @Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line: directive-selector
  selector: "[pageContent]"
})
export class PageContentDirective {

}
```

Comment: I just looked at your question 2 hours ago.
Can I ask for more time to complete my answer?

Comment: @VươngHữuThiện No problem u will have time as mush as u want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is all about dividing the given content to fit into the give page size.

We can create a component that will handle the dividing functionality for us. here is a StackBlitz [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a4-page).

And here is a brief explanation.

Use the `ContentChildren` decorator to observe the change in content. every time the content changes we will run the page creation logic.

```
import {
  AfterContentInit,
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  ContentChildren,
  ElementRef,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  QueryList,
  ViewChild
} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-paginated-view",
  templateUrl: "paginated-view.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["paginated-view.component.scss"]
})
export class PaginatedViewComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() pageSize: "A3" | "A4" = "A4";

  @ViewChild("paginatedView") paginatedView: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

  @ViewChild("contentWrapper") contentWrapper: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

  @ContentChildren("pageContent", { read: ElementRef }) elements: QueryList<
    ElementRef
  >;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.updatePages();

    // when ever childs updated call the updatePagesfunction
    this.elements.changes.subscribe(el => {
      this.updatePages();
    });
  }

  updatePages(): void {
    // clear paginated view
    this.paginatedView.nativeElement.innerHTML = "";

    // get a new page and add it to the paginated view
    let page = this.getNewPage();
    this.paginatedView.nativeElement.appendChild(page);

    let lastEl: HTMLElement;
    // add content childrens to the page one by one
    this.elements.forEach(elRef => {
      const el = elRef.nativeElement;

      // if the content child height is larger than the size of the page
      // then do not add it to the page
      if (el.clientHeight > page.clientHeight) {
        return;
      }
      // add the child to the page
      page.appendChild(el);

      // after adding the child if the page scroll hight becomes larger than the page height
      // then get a new page and append the child to the  new page
      if (page.scrollHeight > page.clientHeight) {
        page = this.getNewPage();
        this.paginatedView.nativeElement.appendChild(page);
        page.appendChild(el);
      }
      lastEl = el;
    });

    //bring the element in to view port
    lastEl.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "nearest" });
  }

  getNewPage(): HTMLDivElement {
    const page = document.createElement("div");
    page.classList.add("page");
    page.classList.add(this.pageSize);
    return page;
  }
}
```

We can use this component in an application like this.

```
<app-paginated-view [pageSize]="'A4'">
    <h1 #pageContent>Hello World!!</h1>
    <p #pageContent>This content will be displayed in an A4 size page</p>
</app-paginated-view>
```

We have to provide the template variable #pageContent so that we can select them using @ContentChildren in our PaginatedViewComponent.

Note that we are using native dom APIs here to change the dom structure. it will only move the dom node from one place to another so if you have any event listener added or have any property binding to the content children they will work as it is.

**Edit:**
I have also updated your stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zjf8rv

Comment: How would you do this that will work of my `json` file see the stacklbitz with my `json`.
Another thing here you have created only if you click button to save data, but I get data from `json`.

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi this component will display its children into the a4 size page no matter where the content is coming from. you can render anything between `<app-paginated-view></app-paginated-view>` and the component will split that content in to multiple a4 size pages.

Comment: I need to write into `<app-paginated-view>` component or where my `ngFor` ?

Comment: In your question you have  written `<div class="A4">` you can replace that div with <app-paginated-view>

Comment: And your code at the `<app-paginated-view`> there to write into my `component` ?

Comment: Yes. you can use the whole PaginatedViewModule from my stackblitz demo. And also can you provide your stackblitz link here in the comment one more time ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223094/discussion-between-hirenparekh-and-abedin-zhuniqi).

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi I have updated my answer and added the updated link of your stackblitz

Comment: I am having issues with the code that you have provided.
Check the new question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64642470/angular-splitting-object-of-array-in-a4-pages-it-is-working-weird-and-not-as-exc

Answer (score 5):

[image]
In app.component.html file:

```
<div class="page" *ngFor="let page of pages; index as i"
  [style.height]="sizePage.height + 'cm'"
  [style.width]="sizePage.width + 'cm'"
  (click)="clickPage(i)">
  <div class="content" 
    [style.paddingTop]="paddingPage.top + 'cm'"
    [style.paddingRight]="paddingPage.right + 'cm'"
    [style.paddingBottom]="paddingPage.bottom + 'cm'"
    [style.paddingLeft]="paddingPage.left + 'cm'"  
    [id]="'content-' + i" contenteditable="true"
    (input)="inputContent($event['data'], i)">
  </div>
</div>
```

In app.component.css file:

```
.page {
    background: white;
    display: block;
    margin: 40px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.page .content {
    overflow: auto;
    outline: 0;
}
```

In app.component.ts file:

```
import { AfterViewChecked, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
  
  sizePage = {
    width: 21, //cm
    height: 29.7 //cm
  }
  paddingPage = {
    top: 2, //cm
    right: 2, //cm
    bottom: 2, //cm
    left: 2 //cm
  }
  pages = [
    {
      htmlContent: null,
      full: false
    },
  ]
  currentPage = 0;
  currentChar = null;

  runAfterViewChecked = false;
  
  clickPage(i) {
    this.currentPage = i;
  }

  inputContent(char, i) {
    var element = document.getElementById('content-' + i)
    var heightContent = element.offsetHeight * 2.54 / 96; // Convert pixels to cm
    this.pages[i].htmlContent = element.innerHTML;
    console.log(this.pages);
    if (Number(heightContent.toFixed(1)) > this.sizePage.height) { 
      this.currentChar = char;
      this.pages[i].full = true;
      if (!this.pages[i + 1]) {
        this.pages.push({
          htmlContent: null,
          full: false
        })
      }
      this.currentPage = i + 1;
      this.runAfterViewChecked = true;
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    document.getElementById('content-' + this.currentPage).focus();
    if (this.runAfterViewChecked) {
      if (this.currentChar) {
        var str = this.pages[this.currentPage-1].htmlContent;
        var indexLastCloseDiv = str.lastIndexOf("</div>");
        var indexLastBr = str.lastIndexOf("<br>");
        var lastChar = str[indexLastCloseDiv-1];
        if (indexLastBr != -1 && (indexLastBr + 4) == indexLastCloseDiv)
          lastChar = ' ';

        if (indexLastCloseDiv != -1)
          str = str.slice(0, indexLastCloseDiv-1) + str.slice(indexLastCloseDiv);
        else 
          str = str.slice(0, str.length - 1);
        this.pages[this.currentPage-1].htmlContent = str;

        if (this.pages[this.currentPage].htmlContent)
          this.pages[this.currentPage].htmlContent = lastChar + this.pages[this.currentPage].htmlContent;
        else
          this.pages[this.currentPage].htmlContent = lastChar;
      }

      var element = null;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.pages.length; i++) {
        element = document.getElementById('content-' + i);
        element.innerHTML = this.pages[i].htmlContent;
      }
      this.runAfterViewChecked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

[Link to Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-split-html-page-in-a4-size-in-angular-9?)

Here is a simple example.
There are a few mistakes, please give your suggestions for further development.

Some functions such as Backspace, Delete, Scale Page, ... have not been processed.

Comment: @vuong Thank you for the time, I tried the stackblitz and it works, but I do have a problem.
Instead input I need to show my Data with ngFor.
How would be that possible ?

Comment: My Input format will have different array of objects.
See this stackblitz, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kk44fj
There I have my `DataModel` and I have some json files as example with my real data.

Comment: This is not very difficult.  But it will take some time.  Currently I am in office hours.  I will try to send you the demo as soon as possible.

Comment: No problem thank you so much.
I am trying to fix it.

Comment: I will give you this bounty.
Because in some minutes will be not available anymore.

Comment: Do you have something new ?

Comment: I have added another bounty are u available to help me ?

Comment: I am doing it for you.
I have used some advanced Angular techniques, so some errors have occurred. I am fixing it.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Good Morning, did you have time to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

It would be fairly easy to force the web browser to display the page with the same pixel dimensions as A4. However, there may be a few quirks when things are rendered.

Assuming your monitors display 72 dpi, you could add something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    body {
        height: 842px;
        width: 595px;
        /* to centre page on screen*/
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here an example in your code with printable A4 size:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fjhpdu?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I think this will not help me so much.

Comment: Each time you can create a pdf with your data  and display it in an HTML document with pagination.
I think this will solve the problem!

Comment: I thought the same, but didnt know where to start.

Comment: Useful javascript library worth is pdfmake.

pdfmake playground --> http://pdfmake.org/playground.html
pdfmake on github --> https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake

Answer (score 2):

If you want to creat html A4 like office word A4 you must use these size:

```
body{
 width: 21cm ;
 height: 29.7cm;
 margin:30mm 45mm 30mm 45mm;}
```

Comment: You are right but my question was more how to create A4 pages depending the Object that I have.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I cant see any js or css by you that attempts to solve the issue.

But looking at the provided example from xing, they are using static pixel width/height

```
width: 595px;
height: 842px;
```

this matches a **PPI** (pixel per inch) of **72** for the given Format A4
thats the only important thing to take in mind.

Knowing that, you can just check if that height is exceeded while editing and manipulate the DOM accordingly ("create new Page", "split/move elements or parts", etc. ...) You should have everything now to solve yourself. But expect that there is a lot of time going into this, especially regarding keeping font sizes / rendering/printring matching and not to talk about the mobile version ;)

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for the time and the idea.
I understand many things from your answer.

Comment: I have created another stackblitz which will be more helpfull I think.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uzmdwg

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In app.component.html file:

```
<div class="container" id="container"></div>
<button type="button" class="buttonAdd" (click)="addBlock()">Add Block</button>
```

In app.component.scss file:

```
.buttonAdd {
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007bff;
    border-color: #007bff;
    padding: .25rem .5rem;
    font-size: .875rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: .2rem;
    top: 0;
}
.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.page {
    // background: white;
    display: block;
    margin: 40px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    .content {
        overflow: auto;
        outline: 0;
        .block {
            border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
            padding: .25rem;
            cursor: default;
            &:hover {
                border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
                border-radius: .25rem;
            }
            .title {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            .value {
                cursor: text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In app.component.ts file:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'], 
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  sizePage = {
    width: 21, //cm
    height: 29.7 //cm
  }
  paddingPage = {
    top: 2, //cm
    right: 2, //cm
    bottom: 2, //cm
    left: 2 //cm
  }

  data = [
    {
      title: "Name_1",
      value: "Thomas K.Wilson"
    }, {
      title: "Email_1",
      value: "thomas.k.wilson@gmail.com"
    }, {
      title: "Telephone_1",
      value: "0123 456 789"
    }, {
      title: "Job_1",
      value: "Teacher"
    }, {
      title: "Name_2",
      value: "Thomas K.Wilson"
    }, {
      title: "Email_2",
      value: "thomas.k.wilson@gmail.com"
    }, {
      title: "Telephone_2",
      value: "0123 456 789"
    }, {
      title: "Job_2",
      value: "Teacher"
    }, {
      title: "Name_3",
      value: "Thomas K.Wilson"
    }, {
      title: "Email_3",
      value: "thomas.k.wilson@gmail.com"
    }, {
      title: "Telephone_3",
      value: "0123 456 789"
    }, {
      title: "Job_3",
      value: "Teacher"
    }, {
      title: "Name_4",
      value: "Thomas K.Wilson"
    }, {
      title: "Email_4",
      value: "thomas.k.wilson@gmail.com"
    }, {
      title: "Telephone_4",
      value: "0123 456 789"
    }, {
      title: "Job_4",
      value: "Teacher"
    }, {
      title: "Name_5",
      value: "Thomas K.Wilson"
    }, {
      title: "Email_5",
      value: "thomas.k.wilson@gmail.com"
    }, {
      title: "Telephone_5",
      value: "0123 456 789"
    }, {
      title: "Job_5",
      value: "Teacher"
    }, {
      title: "Name_6",
      value: "Thomas K.Wilson"
    }, {
      title: "Email_6",
      value: "thomas.k.wilson@gmail.com"
    }, {
      title: "Telephone_6",
      value: "0123 456 789"
    }, {
      title: "Job_6",
      value: "Teacher"
    }, {
      title: "Name_7",
      value: "Thomas K.Wilson"
    }, {
      title: "Email_7",
      value: "thomas.k.wilson@gmail.com"
    }, {
      title: "Telephone_7",
      value: "0123 456 789"
    }, {
      title: "Job_7",
      value: "Teacher"
    }, {
      title: "Name_8",
      value: "Thomas K.Wilson"
    }, {
      title: "Email_8",
      value: "thomas.k.wilson@gmail.com"
    }, {
      title: "Telephone_8",
      value: "0123 456 789"
    }, {
      title: "Job_8",
      value: "Teacher"
    }, {
      title: "Name_9",
      value: "Thomas K.Wilson"
    }, {
      title: "Email_9",
      value: "thomas.k.wilson@gmail.com"
    }, {
      title: "Telephone_9",
      value: "0123 456 789"
    }, {
      title: "Job_9",
      value: "Teacher"
    }, {
      title: "Name_10",
      value: "Thomas K.Wilson"
    }, {
      title: "Email_10",
      value: "thomas.k.wilson@gmail.com"
    }, {
      title: "Telephone_10",
      value: "0123 456 789"
    }, {
      title: "Job_10",
      value: "Teacher"
    }
  ]

  heightPageWithoutPadding = this.convertCmtoPx(this.sizePage.height - (this.paddingPage.top + this.paddingPage.bottom));
  elContainer;
  anchorsBlockValue;
  pageContent = [[]]; // Ex: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]

  constructor (private elementRef: ElementRef){

  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.elContainer = document.getElementById('container');
    this.elContainer.innerHTML += this.createHTMLPage(0);
    this.insertListData();
    this.anchorsBlockValue = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.block .value');
    this.anchorsBlockValue.forEach((anchor: HTMLAnchorElement) => {
      anchor.addEventListener('input', this.handleAnchorBlockValue)
    });
  }

  insertListData() {
    var html_ListBlock = "";
    var html_Block = "";
    var iPage = 0;
    var iBlock = 0;
    var elPageContent = document.getElementById('page-' + iPage + '-content');
    for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
      
      html_Block = this.createHTMLBlock(iPage, iBlock, this.data[i]);
      elPageContent.innerHTML = html_ListBlock + html_Block; 

      if (elPageContent.offsetHeight > this.heightPageWithoutPadding) {
        elPageContent.innerHTML = html_ListBlock;

        iPage += 1;
        this.elContainer.innerHTML += this.createHTMLPage(iPage);
        elPageContent = document.getElementById('page-' + iPage + '-content'); 
        
        this.pageContent[iPage] = [];
        this.pageContent[iPage].push(iBlock);

        html_Block = this.createHTMLBlock(iPage, iBlock, this.data[i]);
        html_ListBlock = html_Block;
        elPageContent.innerHTML = html_ListBlock;
      } else {
        this.pageContent[iPage].push(iBlock);
        
        html_ListBlock += html_Block;
        elPageContent.innerHTML = html_ListBlock;
      }
      iBlock += 1;
    }
    // nodes += `<button type="button" class="buttonAdd" (click)="addBlock()">Add Block</button>`;
  }

  handleAnchorBlockValue = (event: Event) => {
    // Prevent opening anchors the default way
    event.preventDefault();
    const anchor = event.target as HTMLAnchorElement;
    const id_anchorParentEl = anchor.parentElement.getAttribute('id'); // page-iPage-content-block-iBlock
    var iPage = Number(id_anchorParentEl.slice(id_anchorParentEl.indexOf("page-") + ("page-").length, id_anchorParentEl.indexOf("-content")));
    var iBlock = Number(id_anchorParentEl.slice(id_anchorParentEl.indexOf("block-") + ("block-").length, id_anchorParentEl.length));
    var elPageContent = anchor.parentElement.parentElement;
    if (elPageContent.offsetHeight > this.heightPageWithoutPadding) {
      if (!this.pageContent[iPage + 1]) {
        this.elContainer.innerHTML += this.createHTMLPage(iPage + 1);
        this.pageContent[iPage + 1] = [];
      }
      if (this.pageContent[iPage].length == 1) {
        // This is (Height Block == Height Content) > Height Page
        alert("To be continue ...");
      } else {
        while (iPage < this.pageContent.length) {

          var elPageContent = document.getElementById('page-' + iPage + '-content'); 
          var iLastBlock_PageContent = this.pageContent[iPage][this.pageContent[iPage].length - 1];
          var elLastBlock_PageContent = document.getElementById('page-' + iPage + '-content-block-' + iLastBlock_PageContent); 
          elLastBlock_PageContent.remove();
          this.pageContent[iPage].pop();
    
          if (!this.pageContent[iPage + 1]) {
            this.elContainer.innerHTML += this.createHTMLPage(iPage + 1);
            this.pageContent[iPage + 1] = [];
          }

          elLastBlock_PageContent.setAttribute('id', 'page-' + (iPage + 1) + '-content-block-' + iLastBlock_PageContent); 
          var elNextPageContent = document.getElementById('page-' + (iPage + 1) + '-content'); 
          elNextPageContent.innerHTML = elLastBlock_PageContent.outerHTML + elNextPageContent.innerHTML;
          this.pageContent[iPage + 1].unshift(iLastBlock_PageContent);
    
          if (elPageContent.offsetHeight <= this.heightPageWithoutPadding) {
            if (elNextPageContent.offsetHeight <= this.heightPageWithoutPadding) {
              break;
            } else {
              iPage += 1;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      this.anchorsBlockValue = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.block .value');
      this.anchorsBlockValue.forEach((anchor: HTMLAnchorElement) => {
        anchor.addEventListener('input', this.handleAnchorBlockValue)
      });
    }
  }

  addBlock() {
    alert("To be continue ...");
  }

  convertPxToCm(px) {
    return Math.round(px * 2.54/96 * 100) / 100;
  }

  convertCmtoPx(cm) {
    return Math.round(cm * 96/2.54);
  }

  createHTMLBlock(iPage, iBlock, data) {
    return `<div class="block" id="page-${iPage}-content-block-${iBlock}">
              <div class="title">${data.title}</div>
              <div class="value" contenteditable>${data.value}</div>
            </div>`;
  }

  createHTMLPage(iPage) {
    return `<div class="page" id="page-${iPage}" 
              style="
                height: ${this.sizePage.height}cm;
                width: ${this.sizePage.width}cm;
                padding-top: ${this.paddingPage.top}cm;
                padding-right: ${this.paddingPage.right}cm;
                padding-bottom: ${this.paddingPage.bottom}cm;
                padding-left: ${this.paddingPage.left}cm;
              ">
              <div class="content" id="page-${iPage}-content">
              </div>
            </div>`;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // Cleanup by removing the event listeners on destroy
    this.anchorsBlockValue.forEach((anchor: HTMLAnchorElement) => {
      anchor.removeEventListener('input', this.handleAnchorBlockValue)
    })
  }
}
```

In tsconfig.json file:

Add

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"esModuleInterop": true
```

It looks like this

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

[Link to Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-page-in-paper?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I did that after looking at Xing's CV page.

This Block and Data Type design makes it easy to separate columns for the page and add content with arbitrary headings.

You have to convert your data to my data type by adding the dataConvert function in ngOnInit ()

Because you are using the Text data type. If it were more diverse then the data type would be:

```
data = [
    {
      type: "Text",
      title: "Full Name",
      value: "Thomas K.Wilson"
    }, {
      type: "Image",
      title: "My Avatar",
      value: "linkImage.com"
    }
]
```

Comment: And Components which I show the data with `*ngFor` do I need them or not ?
As you can see here.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fjhpdu I show the data into a parent component, I have added like that because every component has it own design and functions.
But I will try that and I will write you, thank you very much.

Comment: When using *ngFor, we will use ngValue, which causes the page to reload when the data content is changed.

Comment: I did that after looking at Xing's CV page.
This Block and Data Type design makes it easy to separate columns for the page and add content with arbitrary headings.

Comment: I will try it and then will respond to you thank you very much.

Comment: Why I am asking again it is because, as you saw in Xing they have multiple templates.
How would be that possible to make with the classes that u have added in TS ?

Comment: I create many stringBlock with different types. When you click the Add Block button, you then choose how the Block type will innerHTML of that type to the Content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223040/discussion-between-vng-hu-thin-and-abedin-zhuniqi).

Answer (score 0):

If you think you can do it with jquery there is no restriction to use jquery in angular

you would need to add following packages

**jQuery** (For jquery ofcourse) https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery

**@types/jquery** (for support in typescript) https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery

Following is the how you can use in your ts file (just for example)

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-a4',
  templateUrl: './a4.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./a4.component.css']
})
export class A4Component implements OnInit {
  max_pages = 5;
  page_count = 0;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.snipMe();
  }

   snipMe() {
    this.page_count++;
    if (this.page_count > this.max_pages) {
      return;
    }
    var long = $(this)[0].scrollHeight - Math.ceil($(this).innerHeight());
    var children = $(this).children().toArray();
    var removed = [];
    while (long > 0 && children.length > 0) {
      var child = children.pop();
      $(child).detach();
      removed.unshift(child);
      long = $(this)[0].scrollHeight - Math.ceil($(this).innerHeight());
    }
    if (removed.length > 0) {
      var a4 = $('<div class="A4"></div>');
      a4.append(removed);
      $(this).after(a4);
      this.snipMe.call(a4[0]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem it is that innerHeight is undefined.

Comment: try debugging that object. see how you could get height.