# Angular Splitting Object of Array in A4 pages it is working weird and not as excepted

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

This question it is a continue of the last question.
[My last question in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64133505/how-to-split-html-page-in-a4-size-in-angular-9)
I am trying to create some `A4` pages within the Objects that I have in the `json` file.
The last guys which answered me it, imediately stopped when I approved the answer.
But the case here it is I need your help to help me further with my problem.
The problem it is that, when the text in one property it is larger then the `A4` page the  directive it doesn't add new page in realtime but only in reload.
I have for example in my `json` tree like this.
Category -> SubCategory -> Properties.
So i need to check if the Category it is larger then `A4`, if the SubCategory is larger and if the property is larger as the height of `A4`.
I am trying to create something like Xing.
https://lebenslauf.com/
The design it look the same but instead editing in the page I have the edit logic in the `modals`

Here is the code what I have tried till now.

`All for A4 pages`

```
<!-- display: none style will any child that does not have #pageContent local variable defined -->
<div class="content-wrapper" #contentWrapper style="display: block">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
<div class="paginated-view" #paginatedView>

</div>

export class PaginatedViewComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() pageSize: "A3" | "A4" = "A4";

  @ViewChild("paginatedView") paginatedView: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

  @ViewChild("contentWrapper") contentWrapper: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

  @ContentChildren(PageContentDirective, { read: ElementRef })
  elements: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.updatePages();

    // when ever childs updated call the updatePagesfunction
    this.elements.changes.subscribe((el) => {
      this.updatePages();
    });
  }


  updatePages(): void {
    // clear paginated view
    this.paginatedView.nativeElement.innerHTML = "";

    // get a new page and add it to the paginated view
    let page = this.getNewPage();
    this.paginatedView.nativeElement.appendChild(page);

    let lastEl: HTMLElement;
    // add content childrens to the page one by one
    this.elements.forEach((elRef) => {
      const el = elRef.nativeElement;

      // if the content child height is larger than the size of the page
      // then do not add it to the page

      if (el.clientHeight > page.clientHeight) {
        return;
      }
      // add the child to the page
      page.appendChild(el);

      // after adding the child if the page scroll hight becomes larger than the page height
      // then get a new page and append the child to the  new page
      if (page.scrollHeight > page.clientHeight) {
        page = this.getNewPage();
        this.paginatedView.nativeElement.appendChild(page);
        page.appendChild(el);
      }
      lastEl = el;
    });
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();

    // bring the element in to view port
   // lastEl.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "nearest" });
  }

  getNewPage(): HTMLDivElement {
    const page = document.createElement("div");
    page.classList.add("page");
    page.classList.add(this.pageSize);
    return page;
  }
}
    @Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line: directive-selector
  selector: "[pageContent]"
})
export class PageContentDirective {

}
```

This is my `HTML` when I try to show data

```
   <div style="transition: transform 0.25s ease 0s;transform: scale(1.3);transform-origin: 50% 0px 0px;backface-visibility: hidden;perspective: 1000px;display: block;margin: 0px 11.5385%;font-size:10px;width: 76.9231%;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;">
<app-paginated-view [pageSize]="'A4'" *ngIf="model" class="Grid-grid-column">
  <div pageContent class="row">
    <div class="col col-lg-7">
      <h4>{{currentUser?.firstName}} {{currentUser?.lastName}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-right">
      <input type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="readUrl($event)">
      <img [src]="url" (change)="readUrl($event)" height="128" style="cursor:  pointer">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div pageContent class="Unit-unit-unitGroup"
   *ngFor="let personalData of model.personalData; let id = index">
   <div pageContent [ngClass]="{ 'isCatActive': selectedCategory === category.PersonalData}">

   <ng-container *ngIf="selectedCategory === category.PersonalData" clickOutside (clickOutside)="removeClick()">
    <ul>
      <li class="fa fa-plus addIconTop" (click)="openDialog()"></li>
      <li class="fa fa-plus addIconBottom" (click)="openDialog()"></li>
      <li class="fa fa-trash deleteIconRight" (click)="deleteCategory(index)"></li>
      <li class="fa fa-arrow-down moveIconDown"></li>
      <li class="fa fa-arrow-up moveIconTop"></li>
    </ul>
  </ng-container>

    <div pageContent class="col-md-12" (click)="setCategory(category.PersonalData)">
      <div class="row height">
      <div  class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-right tLine"></div>
      <h3 class="first-template-paragraphTitle Paragraph-paragraph-title height">
        <div class="Text-text-wrapper">
          <div class="Text-Text-text">{{'category.PersonalData' | translate}}</div>
        </div>
      </h3>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div pageContent class="container-fluid">
      <ng-container>
      <app-personal-data [personalData]="personalData" [model]="model" [id]="id">
    </app-personal-data>
  </ng-container>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

    <!-- Career Component -->
    <ng-container *ngFor="let careers of model.careers" class="Unit-unit-unitGroup">
      <div pageContent class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row height">
        <div  class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-right tLine"></div>
        <h3 class="first-template-paragraphTitle Paragraph-paragraph-title height">
          <div class="Text-text-wrapper">
            <div class="Text-Text-text">{{'category.Career' | translate}}</div>
          </div>
        </h3>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid" pageContent>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let careerObj of careers.subCategories; let i = index">
      <app-career [careerObj]="careerObj" [id]="i" [career]="careers" [model]="model"></app-career>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let emptyObj of careers.emptySubContents; let iEmpty = index">
        <app-empty-object [emptyObj]="emptyObj" [iEmpty]="iEmpty" [model]="model" [isFromCareer]="true"></app-empty-object>
      </ng-container>
        </div>
    </ng-container>

    <!--Education Component-->
    <ng-container *ngFor="let education of model.education" class="Unit-unit-unitGroup">
      <div pageContent [ngClass]="{ 'isCatActive': selectedCategory === category.Education}">
        <ng-container *ngIf="selectedCategory === category.Education" clickOutside (clickOutside)="removeClick()">
          <ul>
            <li class="fa fa-plus addIconTop" (click)="openDialog()"></li>
            <li class="fa fa-plus addIconBottom" (click)="openDialog()"></li>
            <li class="fa fa-trash deleteIconRight" (click)="deleteCategory(index)"></li>
            <li class="fa fa-arrow-down moveIconDown"></li>
            <li class="fa fa-arrow-up moveIconTop"></li>
          </ul>
        </ng-container>
      <div pageContent class="col-md-12" (click)="setCategory(category.Education)">
        <div class="row height">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-right tLine"></div>
          <h3 class="first-template-paragraphTitle Paragraph-paragraph-title height">
            <div class="Text-text-wrapper">
              <div class="Text-Text-text">{{'category.Education' | translate}}</div>
            </div>
          </h3>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div pageContent class="container-fluid">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let educationObj of education.subCategories; let i = index" class="col-md-12">
        <app-education [educationObj]="educationObj" [id]="i" [education]="education" [model]="model"></app-education>
      </ng-container>
      </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>


  <!-- Skills Component-->
    <ng-container *ngFor="let skills of model.skills" class="Unit-unit-unitGroup">
    <div pageContent [ngClass]="{ 'isCatActive': selectedCategory === category.Skills}">
    <ng-container clickOutside *ngIf="selectedCategory === category.Skills" (clickOutside)="removeClick()">
      <ul>
        <li class="fa fa-plus addIconTop" (click)="openDialog()"></li>
        <li class="fa fa-plus addIconBottom" (click)="openDialog()"></li>
        <li class="fa fa-trash deleteIconRight" (click)="deleteCategory(index)"></li>
        <li class="fa fa-arrow-down moveIconDown"></li>
        <li class="fa fa-arrow-up moveIconTop"></li>
      </ul>
    </ng-container>
    <div pageContent class="col-md-12" (click)="setCategory(category.Skills)">
      <div class="row height">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-right tLine"></div>
        <h3 class="first-template-paragraphTitle Paragraph-paragraph-title height">
          <div class="Text-text-wrapper">
            <div class="Text-Text-text">{{'category.Skills' | translate}}</div>
          </div>
        </h3>
    </div>
    </div>
          <div pageContent class="container-fluid">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let skillObj of skills.subCategories; let i = index" class="col-md-12">
        <app-skills [skillObj]="skillObj" [id]="i" [skills]="skills" [model]="model"></app-skills>
      </ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>


</app-paginated-view>
</div>
```

And this is the `css`

```
.A4 {
  width: 595px;
  height: 842px;
  padding: 25px 25px;
  position: relative;
}
```

If you want to see more code, here is the stackblitz.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zjf8rv)

And here is the screenshot which is the current design.
As you can see here the space in the Career it is very large it should not be like that.
It should add the text based on the height and if is alrger then cut the text and the other text add to new page.
[image]

Comment: I have seen somebody voted to close.
I want the reason of it. I specified what is my problem, dont be like this only close one question.
There are many people which can take or learn from the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223094/discussion-between-hirenparekh-and-abedin-zhuniqi)